# Wordpress:only header appears and all content disappeared after i moved to different server

Tags: wordpress, vps

i moved my entire wordpress file to new VPS.
i set up all required thing to run wordpress(mysql,httpd etc..)

since my wordpress website has lots of content i thought it will be bad idea to install new wordpress on new VPS and import database, set up all plugin settings so i just downloaded all file related to wordpress and uploaded on new VPS.

i had a permalink problem on new VPS, but it fixed by rewriting .htaccess

but now i have different problem, which wordpress only loads header and all content is just disappears.

nothing wrong with template file(just copied full file that works fine on old server), and it should load my entire pages but still only header will appears.

Comment: Have you updated the URL's within the WP database?

Comment: @David.J im not going to change urls. same domain, same url.

Comment: ofcource i already imported old wordpress database to new servers database.

Comment: Checked the error logs?

Comment: @David.J yeah. seems to be fine as well.

Comment: Disable all plugins / child theme and activate Twenty16 - what is the result?